# How do I remove iTunes downloads without deleting from my library?

Tags: itunes, music

iTunes has an option that I've used often in the past, I believe it was named Remove Download, to "undo" the download of a song or album (I've used it to free up space and to re-download music into different folders). However, I no longer see the option to do this, and I can't figure out why.

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on an old MacBook Air. I'm not subscribed to Apple Music or iTunes Match (subscribing to either one is not an option right now). My account is set up with Family Sharing.

Thank you!

*(Image: a screenshot of the menu that appears when I right-click a song.)*

[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-27 at 2.56.18 PM]

Answer (score 1):

On my computer running 10.14.6 and iTunes 12.9.5.5, clicking the "Delete from library" brings up an option to either just remove the download or remove it from from the library entirely.